# SQL Server stored procedure performance issue - WHILE EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I was wondering if anything jumped out at the experts as to why my stored procedure takes so long.

The procedure tries to insert/update transactions/records in a master table only if it passes some rules.

If it fails it insert/updates the transactions/records in another table.

The procedure for a 45,000 line takes around 5-8 mins.

It works perfectly as is, but it takes so long and I know my tables in a couple of months will be +1million records so I'm nervous how long it will take then.

I've looked at CTE as an option but unsure how to use.

Note: I actually find including a temporary table faster then querying the staging table directly.

**What is the goal**

The main goal is to make sure each record being inserted into the final table is valid.

If a record is valid, it then checks if that record already exists in the final table, If it does it tries to update that record (if details have changed). If it doesn't already exist it inserts a new.

Similarly if a record is invalid/errors, then check if that record already exists in another non-final table, If it does it tries to update that record (if details have changed). It it doesn't already exist it inserts a new. In this table is where the error messages are included.

To be valid a record

- Firm ID must be in manager_mapping
- Product ID must be in product_mapping
- CCY must be in dim_ccy
- Returns must be numeric
- Value Date must be date

Note: I do not instant throw when an error is found when validating. @ErrorCode & @ErrorMessage are built up and up to be as descriptive as possible

**SQL Code**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ETL_stage_evestment_performance_to_champ_2.0]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /*Variable Declaration*/
    DECLARE
        @BatchImportID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @FileProcessedDate DATETIME,
        @FileProcessedUTCDate DATETIME,
        @ImportStatus TINYINT,
        @ErrorCode VARCHAR(2000),
        @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(4000),
        @StagingID INT,
        @value_date VARCHAR(255),
        @firm_id VARCHAR(255),      
        @product_id VARCHAR(255),
        @vehicle_id VARCHAR(255),
        @ccy VARCHAR(255),
        @reporting_method VARCHAR(255),
        @performance_return VARCHAR(255),
        @log_return VARCHAR(255)

    /*Assign static value for whole one time process*/
    SELECT
        @BatchImportID = NEWID(),
        @FileProcessedDate = GETDATE(),
        @FileProcessedUTCDate = GETUTCDATE()

    /*Create staging table so we can re-run procedure instead of having to rerun complete task again and again*/
    CREATE TABLE #stagingPerformance
    (
            [index] [BIGINT] NULL,
            [value_date] [DATETIME] NULL,                       
            [firm_id] [BIGINT] NULL,
            [ccy] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
            [product_id] [BIGINT] NULL,
            [reporting_method] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
            [vehicle_id] [BIGINT] NULL,
            [performance_return] [FLOAT] NULL,
            [log_return] [FLOAT] NULL
    )

    CREATE INDEX [IX_EvestmentData_1] 
    ON #stagingPerformance ([index] ASC, [value_date] ASC, [firm_id] ASC)

    -- POPULATE TEMP TABLE
    INSERT INTO #stagingPerformance
        SELECT 
            a.[index], a.value_date, a.firm_id, a.ccy, 
            a.product_id, a.reporting_method, a.vehicle_id, 
            a.performance_return, a.log_return
        FROM
            CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_staging_evestment_performance a

    /*While loop started to get process record one by one*/
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #stagingPerformance AS FHD WITH (NOLOCK))
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

            /*To assign 1 record values to respective variables*/
            SELECT TOP 1
                @StagingID = FHD.[index],
                @firm_id = NULLIF(FHD.[firm_id],''),
                @product_id = NULLIF(FHD.[product_id],''),
                @vehicle_id = NULLIF(FHD.[vehicle_id],''),
                @value_date = NULLIF(FHD.[value_date],''),
                @reporting_method = NULLIF(FHD.[reporting_method],''),              
                @ccy = NULLIF(FHD.[ccy],''),                
                @performance_return = NULLIF(FHD.[performance_return],''),
                @log_return = NULLIF(FHD.[log_return],'')               
            FROM 
                #stagingPerformance AS FHD WITH (NOLOCK)
            ORDER BY 
                FHD.[index]

            /*Record wise validation start*/
            IF @reporting_method IS NOT NULL 
               AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 WHERE @reporting_method in ('Gross', 'Net', 'Index')) 
            BEGIN
                SELECT
                    @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '115',
                    @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Reporting Method is invalid'
            END

            IF @value_date IS NOT NULL AND ISDATE(@value_date) = 0 
            BEGIN
                SELECT
                    @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '106',
                    @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Invalid value of Value Date.'
            END

            IF @performance_return IS NOT NULL  
               AND ISNUMERIC(@performance_return) = 0 
            BEGIN
                SELECT
                    @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + CASE WHEN @ErrorCode LIKE '%112%' THEN '' ELSE ',' + '112' END,
                    @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Invalid value of performance.'
            END

            IF @log_return IS NOT NULL AND ISNUMERIC(@log_return) = 0 
            BEGIN
                SELECT
                    @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + CASE WHEN @ErrorCode LIKE '%112%' THEN '' ELSE ',' + '112' END,
                    @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Invalid value of log_return.'
            END

            IF @firm_id IS NOT NULL 
               AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                              FROM CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_fund_manager_mapping AS DFM WITH (NOLOCK) 
                              WHERE DFM.evestment_fund_manager_id = @firm_id)
            BEGIN
                SELECT
                    @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '113',
                    @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Firm ID not Mapped'
            END

            IF @product_id IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.champ_dw_product_mapping AS DAM WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE DAM.evestment_product_id=@product_id)
            BEGIN
                SELECT
                    @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '114',
                    @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Product ID is not Mapped'
            END

            IF @ccy IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].champ_dw_dim_currency AS DC WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE DC.currency = @ccy) BEGIN
                SELECT
                    @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + ',' + '112',
                    @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + ',' + 'Invalid CCY'
            END

            SELECT
                @ErrorCode = NULLIF(STUFF(@ErrorCode,1,1,''),''),
                @ErrorMessage = NULLIF(STUFF(@ErrorMessage,1,1,''),'')

            IF @ErrorMessage IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                ;THROW 50552,'VALIDATION RAISE ERROR.',1
            END

            /*Record wise validation end*/

            /*To get unique record value based on columns*/

            DECLARE
                @performance_id bigint = 0,
                @vfirm_id INT,
                @vproduct_id INT,
                @vvehicle_id INT,
                @vvalue_date datetime2,
                @vreporting_method nvarchar(max),
                @vccy nvarchar(3),
                @vperformance_return float,
                @vlog_return float,             
                @map_firm_id INT,
                @map_product_id INT

            SELECT
                @vfirm_id = TRY_PARSE(@firm_id AS INT),
                @vproduct_id = TRY_PARSE(@product_id AS INT),
                @vvehicle_id = TRY_PARSE(@vehicle_id AS INT),
                @vvalue_date = TRY_PARSE(@value_date AS datetime2),
                @vreporting_method = @reporting_method,
                @vccy = cast(@ccy as nvarchar(3)),
                @vperformance_return = TRY_PARSE(@performance_return AS float),
                @vlog_return = TRY_PARSE(@log_return AS float)

            SELECT 
                @map_firm_id = (SELECT fund_manager_mapping_id FROM CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_fund_manager_mapping fm WHERE fm.evestment_fund_manager_id = @vfirm_id),
                @map_product_id = (SELECT product_mapping_id FROM CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_product_mapping fp  WHERE fp.product_mapping_id=@vvehicle_id)

            SELECT 
                @performance_id = FFHD.performance_id 
            FROM dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance] AS FFHD WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE FFHD.fund_manager_id = @map_firm_id
                AND FFHD.product_id = @map_product_id
                AND FFHD.value_date = @vvalue_date
                AND FFHD.data_source = 'eVestment'
                AND FFHD.ccy_id = @vccy
                AND FFHD.reporting_method = @vreporting_method

                IF @performance_id IS NOT NULL or @performance_id = 0
                    BEGIN
                        /*Update record, if any value has different then already exist in DB.*/
                        UPDATE FFHD
                        SET 
                            FFHD.ccy_id = @ccy,
                            FFHD.performance_return = @vperformance_return,
                            FFHD.log_return = @vlog_return          
                        FROM dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance] AS FFHD WITH (NOLOCK)
                        WHERE FFHD.performance_id = @performance_id
                        AND
                        (
                            ISNULL(FFHD.performance_return,'0') <> @vperformance_return
                            OR
                            ISNULL(FFHD.log_return,'0') <> @vlog_return
                        )
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        /*Add new record */         
                        INSERT INTO dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance]
                        (
                            value_date,
                            reporting_method,
                            valuation_quality,
                            data_source,
                            performance_return,
                            log_return,
                            ccy_id,
                            fund_manager_id,
                            product_id              
                        )
                        SELECT
                            @vvalue_date AS value_date,
                            @vreporting_method AS reporting_method,
                            'Actual' as valuation_quality,
                            'eVestment' as data_source,
                            @vperformance_return AS performance_return,
                            @vlog_return AS log_return,
                            @vccy AS ccy_id,
                            @map_firm_id AS fund_manager_id_id,
                            @map_product_id AS product_id_id
                    END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION  

        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH

            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            END

            BEGIN TRANSACTION

                DECLARE
                    @ERROR_MESSAGE NVARCHAR(4000)
                SELECT
                    @ERROR_MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE()

                IF @ERROR_MESSAGE <> 'VALIDATION RAISE ERROR.'
                BEGIN
                    SELECT
                        @ErrorCode = ISNULL(@ErrorCode,'') + CASE WHEN ISNULL(@ERROR_MESSAGE,'') <> '' THEN ',' + '999' ELSE '' END,
                        @ErrorMessage = ISNULL(@ErrorMessage,'') + CASE WHEN ISNULL(@ERROR_MESSAGE,'') <> '' THEN ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000),@ERROR_MESSAGE) ELSE '' END
                END

                SELECT
                    @ErrorCode = NULLIF(CASE WHEN @ErrorCode LIKE '%999%' THEN STUFF(@ErrorCode,1,1,'') ELSE @ErrorCode END,''),
                    @ErrorMessage = NULLIF(CASE WHEN @ErrorCode LIKE '%999%' THEN STUFF(@ErrorMessage,1,1,'') ELSE @ErrorMessage END,'')

                /*To add failed record to table*/

            SELECT 
                @performance_id = FFHD.AutoLogID
            FROM dbo.champ_dw_evestment_performance AS FFHD WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE FFHD.firm_id = @vfirm_id
                AND FFHD.product_id = @vproduct_id
                AND FFHD.vehicle_id = @vvehicle_id
                AND FFHD.value_date = @vvalue_date
                AND FFHD.ccy_id = @vccy
                AND FFHD.reporting_method = @vreporting_method

                IF @performance_id IS NOT NULL or @performance_id = 0
                    BEGIN
                        /*Update failed record, if any value has different then already exist in DB.*/
                        UPDATE FFHD
                        SET 
                            FFHD.performance_return = @vperformance_return,
                            FFHD.log_return = @vlog_return,
                            FFHD.BatchImportID = @BatchImportID,
                            FFHD.FileProcessedDate = @FileProcessedDate,
                            FFHD.FileProcessedUTCDate = @FileProcessedUTCDate,
                            FFHD.ErrorCode = @ErrorCode,
                            FFHD.ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage   
                        FROM dbo.champ_dw_evestment_performance AS FFHD WITH (NOLOCK)
                        WHERE FFHD.AutoLogID = @performance_id
                        AND
                        (
                            ISNULL(FFHD.performance_return,'0') <> @vperformance_return
                            OR
                            ISNULL(FFHD.log_return,'0') <> @vlog_return
                        )
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        /*Add new record */         
                        INSERT INTO dbo.champ_dw_evestment_performance
                        (
                            BatchImportID,
                            FileProcessedDate,
                            FileProcessedUTCDate,
                            ImportStatus,
                            ErrorCode,
                            ErrorMessage,
                            value_date,
                            reporting_method,
                            ccy_id,
                            performance_return,
                            log_return,
                            firm_id,
                            product_id,
                            vehicle_id
                        )
                        SELECT
                            @BatchImportID AS BatchImportID,
                            @FileProcessedDate AS FileProcessedDate,
                            @FileProcessedUTCDate AS FileProcessedUTCDate,
                            0 AS ImportStatus,
                            @ErrorCode AS ErrorCode,
                            @ErrorMessage AS ErrorMessage,
                            @value_date AS value_date,
                            @reporting_method AS reporting_method,
                            @ccy AS ccy_id,
                            @performance_return AS performance_return,
                            @log_return AS log_return,
                            @firm_id AS firm_id,
                            @product_id AS product_id,
                            @vehicle_id AS vehicle_id
                    END

            COMMIT TRANSACTION

        END CATCH;

        DELETE FHD
        FROM #stagingPerformance AS FHD
        WHERE FHD.[index] = @StagingID

        SELECT
            @performance_id = NULL,
            @StagingID = NULL,
            @firm_id = NULL,
            @product_id = NULL,
            @vehicle_id = NULL,
            @value_date = NULL,
            @reporting_method = NULL,
            @ccy = NULL,
            @performance_return = NULL,
            @log_return = NULL,
            @ImportStatus = NULL,
            @ErrorCode = NULL,
            @ErrorMessage = NULL
    END

    SELECT @BatchImportID as 'BatchID'

    DROP TABLE #stagingPerformance  

END
```

**UPDATE WORKING SOLUTION - 6 Seconds from down from 20mins**

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ETL_stage_evestment_performance_to_champ_2.0_New]
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
            DECLARE
            @BatchImportID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
            @FileProcessedDate DATETIME,
            @FileProcessedUTCDate DATETIME,
            @ImportStatus TINYINT,
            @ErrorCode VARCHAR(2000),
            @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(4000),
            @StagingID INT,
            @value_date VARCHAR(255),
            @firm_id VARCHAR(255),      
            @product_id VARCHAR(255),
            @vehicle_id VARCHAR(255),
            @ccy VARCHAR(255),
            @reporting_method VARCHAR(255),
            @performance_return VARCHAR(255),
            @log_return VARCHAR(255)

        /*Assign static value for whole one time process*/
        SELECT
            @BatchImportID = NEWID(),
            @FileProcessedDate = GETDATE(),
            @FileProcessedUTCDate = GETUTCDATE()

        /*Create staging table so we can re-run procedure instead of having to rerun complete task again and again*/

        DECLARE @stagingPerformance TABLE (
                [index] [BIGINT] NULL,
                [value_date] [DATETIME] NULL,                       
                [firm_id] [BIGINT] NULL,
                [ccy] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
                [product_id] [BIGINT] NULL,
                [reporting_method] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
                [vehicle_id] [BIGINT] NULL,
                [performance_return] [FLOAT] NULL,
                [log_return] [FLOAT] NULL,
                [ErrorCode] NVARCHAR(MAX),
                [ErrorMessage] NVARCHAR(MAX)
            )

        -- POPULATE 1st Staging Table with Data and Error Codes and Error Messages
        INSERT INTO @stagingPerformance
            SELECT 
                a.[index],
                NULLIF(a.value_date,''),
                NULLIF(a.firm_id,''),
                NULLIF(a.ccy,''), 
                NULLIF(a.product_id,''),
                NULLIF(a.reporting_method,''), 
                NULLIF(a.vehicle_id,''), 
                NULLIF(a.performance_return,''),
                NULLIF(a.log_return,''),
                '' as ErrorCode,
                '' as ErrorMessage
            FROM
                CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_staging_evestment_performance a


            /* Have one update, but set one variable concatenated
                or alternatively change the below to have multiple updates per condition and then you are able to set multiple variables per condition*/
            UPDATE @stagingPerformance

                SET ErrorCode = 
                    CASE WHEN reporting_method IS NOT NULL AND reporting_method IN ('Gross', 'Net', 'Index')
                    THEN ''
                    ELSE ','+'115'
                    END
                    +
                    CASE WHEN value_date IS NOT NULL AND ISDATE(value_date) = 1 
                    THEN ''
                    ELSE ','+'106'
                    END
                    +
                    CASE WHEN firm_id IS NOT NULL AND DFM.evestment_fund_manager_id IS NOT NULL 
                    THEN ''
                    ELSE ','+'113' 
                    END 
                    +
                    CASE WHEN product_id IS NOT NULL AND DAM.evestment_product_id IS NOT NULL 
                    THEN ''
                    ELSE ','+'114'
                    END
                    +                               
                    CASE WHEN ccy IS NOT NULL AND DC.currency IS NOT NULL 
                    THEN ''
                    ELSE ','+'112' 
                    END

                ,ErrorMessage= 
                    CASE WHEN reporting_method IS NOT NULL AND  reporting_method IN ('Gross', 'Net', 'Index')
                    THEN ''
                    ELSE ','+'Invalid Reporting Method'--115 
                    END
                    +
                    CASE WHEN value_date IS NOT NULL AND ISDATE(value_date) = 1 
                    THEN ''
                    ELSE ','+'Invalid Value Date'--106
                    END
                    +
                    CASE WHEN firm_id IS NOT NULL AND DFM.evestment_fund_manager_id IS NOT NULL 
                    THEN ''
                    ELSE ','+'Unmapped Firm' --113
                    END 
                    +
                    CASE WHEN product_id IS NOT NULL AND DAM.evestment_product_id IS NOT NULL 
                    THEN ''
                    ELSE ','+'Unmapped Product' --114
                    END
                    +                               
                    CASE WHEN ccy IS NOT NULL AND DC.currency IS NOT NULL 
                    THEN ''
                    ELSE ','+'Invalid CCY' --112
                    END

            FROM
                @stagingPerformance a 
                LEFT JOIN CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_fund_manager_mapping AS DFM ON DFM.evestment_fund_manager_id = a.firm_id
                LEFT JOIN CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_product_mapping DAM ON DAM.evestment_product_id = a.product_id
                LEFT JOIN CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_dim_currency AS DC WITH (NOLOCK) ON DC.currency = a.ccy


            /* Remove leading "," */
            UPDATE @stagingPerformance
            SET ErrorCode = STUFF(ErrorCode,1,1,'')
            WHERE ErrorCode LIKE ',%'

            UPDATE @stagingPerformance
            SET ErrorMessage= STUFF(ErrorMessage,1,1,'')
            WHERE ErrorMessage LIKE ',%'

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /* RECORD HANDLING (Records without validation errors) */
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            DECLARE @stagingPerformanceNoError TABLE (
                    do_create bit,
                    performance_id BIGINT,
                    vfirm_id BIGINT NULL,
                    vproduct_id BIGINT,
                    vvehicle_id BIGINT,
                    vvalue_date datetime2,
                    vreporting_method nvarchar(max),
                    vccy nvarchar(3),
                    vperformance_return float,
                    vlog_return float,             
                    map_firm_id INT,
                    map_product_id INT

            )

            /* Move from Staging Table 1 to Staging Table 2 all records without errors */
            INSERT INTO  @stagingPerformanceNoError              

                    SELECT 

                    CASE WHEN FFHD.performance_id  IS NOT NULL AND 
                    (
                        ISNULL(FFHD.performance_return,'0') <> a.performance_return
                        OR
                        ISNULL(FFHD.log_return,'0') <> a.log_return
                    )
                    THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS do_create,--create 1=update 0 /*Same Criteria as before to decide when to Insert or when to Update */
                    FFHD.performance_id  as performance_id,
                    a.firm_id,
                    a.product_id,
                    a.vehicle_id,
                    a.value_date,
                    a.reporting_method,
                    a.ccy, --char 3
                    a.performance_return,
                    a.log_return,
                    fm.fund_manager_mapping_id as map_firm_id,--map_firm_id
                    fp.product_mapping_id as map_product_id--map_product_id

            FROM @stagingPerformance a 
            LEFT JOIN CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_fund_manager_mapping fm ON fm.evestment_fund_manager_id = a.firm_id 
            LEFT JOIN CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_product_mapping fp  ON fp.product_mapping_id=a.vehicle_id
            LEFT JOIN  CHAMP_DW.dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance] AS FFHD
                ON FFHD.fund_manager_id = fm.fund_manager_mapping_id
                    AND FFHD.product_id = fp.product_mapping_id
                    AND FFHD.value_date = a.value_date
                    AND FFHD.data_source = 'eVestment'
                    AND FFHD.ccy_id = ccy
                    AND FFHD.reporting_method = a.reporting_method
            WHERE a.ErrorCode='' /* Only records without errors are moved to staging table 2*/


            /*Update record, if any value has different then already exist in DB.*/
            UPDATE CHAMP_DW.dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance]
            SET 
                ccy_id = a.vccy,
                performance_return = a.vperformance_return,
                log_return = a.vlog_return          
            FROM dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance] AS FFHD WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN @stagingPerformanceNoError a ON a.performance_id=FFHD.performance_id 
            WHERE do_create=0 /*Update*/

            /*Add new record */         
            INSERT INTO dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance]
            (
                value_date,
                reporting_method,
                valuation_quality,
                data_source,
                performance_return,
                log_return,
                ccy_id,
                fund_manager_id,
                product_id              
            )
            SELECT
                vvalue_date AS value_date,
                vreporting_method AS reporting_method,
                'Actual' as valuation_quality,
                'eVestment' as data_source,
                vperformance_return AS performance_return,
                vlog_return AS log_return,
                vccy AS ccy_id,
                map_firm_id AS fund_manager_id_id,
                map_product_id AS product_id_id
            FROM @stagingPerformanceNoError
            WHERE do_create=1 /*Insert*/
            AND performance_id  IS  NULL



    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /* ERROR HANDLING - Records with Validation ERRORS */
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



        DECLARE @stagingPerformanceError TABLE (
                [performance_id] [BIGINT] NULL,
                [index] [BIGINT] NULL,
                [value_date] [DATETIME] NULL,                       
                [firm_id] [BIGINT] NULL,
                [ccy] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
                [product_id] [BIGINT] NULL,
                [reporting_method] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
                [vehicle_id] [BIGINT] NULL,
                [performance_return] [FLOAT] NULL,
                [log_return] [FLOAT] NULL,
                [ErrorCode] NVARCHAR(MAX),
                [ErrorMessage] NVARCHAR(MAX)
            )


        -- POPULATE Error Table
        INSERT INTO @stagingPerformanceError
            SELECT 
                NULL, --performance_id
                a.[index],
                NULLIF(a.value_date,''),
                NULLIF(a.firm_id,''),
                NULLIF(a.ccy,''), 
                NULLIF(a.product_id,''),
                NULLIF(a.reporting_method,''), 
                NULLIF(a.vehicle_id,''), 
                NULLIF(a.performance_return,''),
                NULLIF(a.log_return,''),
                NULLIF(a.ErrorCode,''),
                NULLIF(a.ErrorMessage,'')
            FROM
                @stagingPerformance a
            WHERE a.ErrorCode<>''


            UPDATE @stagingPerformanceError
                SET performance_id= FFHD.AutoLogID
                FROM @stagingPerformanceError a 
                INNER JOIN dbo.champ_dw_evestment_performance AS FFHD 
                ON FFHD.firm_id = a.firm_id
                    AND FFHD.product_id = a.product_id
                    AND FFHD.vehicle_id = a.vehicle_id
                    AND FFHD.value_date = a.value_date
                    AND FFHD.ccy_id = a.ccy
                    AND FFHD.reporting_method = a.reporting_method


                /*Update failed record, if any value has different then already exist in DB.*/
                UPDATE FFHD
                SET 
                    FFHD.performance_return = a.performance_return,
                    FFHD.log_return = a.log_return,
                    FFHD.BatchImportID = @BatchImportID,
                    FFHD.FileProcessedDate = @FileProcessedDate,
                    FFHD.FileProcessedUTCDate = @FileProcessedUTCDate,
                    FFHD.ErrorCode = @ErrorCode,
                    FFHD.ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage   
                FROM dbo.champ_dw_evestment_performance AS FFHD
                INNER JOIN @stagingPerformanceError a ON FFHD.AutoLogID = a.performance_id
                WHERE FFHD.AutoLogID = a.performance_id
                AND
                (
                    ISNULL(FFHD.performance_return,'0') <> a.performance_return
                    OR
                    ISNULL(FFHD.log_return,'0') <> a.log_return
                )
                AND a.performance_id IS NOT NULL


                /*Add new record */         
                INSERT INTO dbo.champ_dw_evestment_performance
                (
                    BatchImportID,
                    FileProcessedDate,
                    FileProcessedUTCDate,
                    ImportStatus,
                    ErrorCode,
                    ErrorMessage,
                    value_date,
                    reporting_method,
                    ccy_id,
                    performance_return,
                    log_return,
                    firm_id,
                    product_id,
                    vehicle_id
                )
                SELECT
                    @BatchImportID AS BatchImportID,
                    @FileProcessedDate AS FileProcessedDate,
                    @FileProcessedUTCDate AS FileProcessedUTCDate,
                    0 AS ImportStatus,
                    A.ErrorCode AS ErrorCode,
                    a.ErrorMessage AS ErrorMessage,
                    a.value_date AS value_date,
                    a.reporting_method AS reporting_method,
                    a.ccy AS ccy_id,
                    a.performance_return AS performance_return,
                    a.log_return AS log_return,
                    a.firm_id AS firm_id,
                    a.product_id AS product_id,
                    a.vehicle_id AS vehicle_id

                FROM @stagingPerformanceError a
                WHERE a.performance_id IS  NULL
    END
```

Comment: `why my stored procedure takes so long` - SQL is set based language and [RBAR: ‘Row By Agonizing Row’](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) here loop  is the slowest approach. You should rewrite procedure to do your operations for all rows at once

Comment: I agree loop is the slowest approach, I'm just struggling how to re-write to batch this type of validation query....

Comment: What is your SP trying to achieve here? As Lukasz said, using a `WHILE` is a big problem here; if we can understand your goals perhaps we can help you rewrite it.

Comment: When processing row-by-row it's very important to use a transaction, otherwise the log must be flushed after each row.

Comment: @Larnu the main goal is to make sure each record is valid. To be valid a record must have a firm and product mapping in some master tables, have a valid ccy, a valid date and return numbers must be numeric. I went row by row because I thought it was the best way to be fully descriptive when logging errors.

Comment: @Larnu the transaction is _inside_ the loop.  It should be _outside_.

Comment: That's not a lot for us to go on there, @RachOdwyer. YOu need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft you're right, I'd misread (it is getting late here).

Comment: I've tried to update, more with greater explanation of whats happening here

Comment: I'm not going to go through your whole proc, but the general idea is... write a single select statement (not in a loop) that select _ALL_ records from staging that don't have a required record in the other table. Then you can insert all of those records in one go, along with error messages into your logging table.

Comment: You can create a temp table that will hold all records together with an additional column that will indicate if a record is valid, and with additional one column for each of your if validation statements - in these columns you'll indicate that a row has an error of exactly this certain type. As you populate the new temp table (with a single insert), you'll calculate whether a record is valid or what validation errors it contains. Then instead of having per row inserts/updates, you can in one go update/insert other tables such as logging table by joining the new temp table with the targeted one

Comment: I like the logic/sound of that @milosmilosavljevic... Just now have to figure out some logic around those extra columns, the joins and the errors

Comment: I really don't think a temp table is particularly necessary or relevant. The real problem is you are doing RBAR operations instead of set based operations.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The real problem is doing RBAR instead of set based operations, i fully agree. The only reason I introduced temp table is that I found them convenient to give a (relatively) simple example of how you can possibly transition from RBAR to set based thinking. This can of course be accomplished in numerous other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some examples of using a set based operations instead of RBAR. These simply do the whole operation in one go rather than slowly looping around.

I may have missed something due to the complexity of your proc but this gives you an idea

This first one is simple - just update a record based on a where clause

```
  update dbo.champ_dw_evestment_performance
  set ErrorMessage  =  ISNULL(ErrorMessage,'') + 'Reporting Method is invalid'
  where reporting_method NOT IN ('Gross', 'Net', 'Index')
  and reporting_method IS NOT NULL
```

This marks *all* of the records in one go rather than slowly looping around

Secondly here is an example of a update again with a where but this one has a "correlated" join inside the exists

```
  update TGT
  set ErrorMessage  =  ISNULL(ErrorMessage,'') + 'Firm ID not Mapped'
  FROM dbo.champ_dw_evestment_performance AS TGT
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM CHAMP_DW.dbo.champ_dw_fund_manager_mapping AS DFM
      WHERE DFM.evestment_fund_manager_id = TGT.firm_id
  )
```

You should be able to use those two concepts to remove a lot of those updates from your loop.

With regards to the update to `dbo.[champ_dw_fact_performance]`.. I can't follow what you're doing here but I'm 95% certain you can also do it in one statement although it will have a few joins in it.

I don't think I saw *any* joins in your code. You really need to learn about those.

So if this makes some sense to you and you'd like me to attack the champ_dw_fact_performance update let me know. It's a bit of effort to untangle it

Comment: Amazing ideas, thank you. I’ll use these base concepts and work on re-writing to batch. I’m pretty confident I will be able to implement, however I may post back here for code review please. Only if people have the time. Thanks again all

Comment: Optimising this proc will not be trivial. I suggest you make some initial changes and get as far as you can then ask another question, referencing this one.